# How To Log to Different Level when Using Node StackDriver Client Library?

Tags: node.js, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm using [StackDriver client library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging) but can't find a way to make it log to INFO, WARN, ERROR, etc...

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. All it takes is putting `serverity` to metadata before creating an entry.

```js
const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const logging = new Logging({ projectId: "proj1" });
const log = logging.log("proj1", { removeCircular: true });

const metadata = {
    resource: {type: 'global'},
    severity: 'CRITICAL' // << HERE WHERE WE SHOULD PUT LOG LEVEL
};
const entry = log.entry(resource, "something happened");
log.write(entry);
```

Available levels are `DEFAULT`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `NOTICE`, `WARNING`, `ERROR`, `CRITICAL`, `ALERT` and `EMERGENCY`

#### References

- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogSeverity
- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry